# SoundCloud API Downloadable Tracks Filtering

Tags: soundcloud

I'm going to develop sound cloud based music app and having an issue at filtering.

What I want is to filter downloadable tracks at sound cloud.
I've seen the sound cloud developers' API guide and made the following request.

"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&limit=10&q=最炫民族风&filter=downloadable&order=hotness&client_id=11111111111111111111111"

But this request doesn't return downloadable songs only, and there is downloadable|non-downloadable tracks in the returned track list.

Would you please tell me the correct request for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the best thing to do is filter them after retrieving them. This would return less than the number of songs you requested though.